# Is it possible to change the parent of a menu item at certain widths?

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu-item, menu, submenu

I have a horizontal main menu in which the last item is a dropdown containing further items.

Is it possible, as the screen width is reduced, to move items from the horizontal menu into the dropdown?

Current menu structure is like so:

Item 1 
Item 2 
Item 3 
Item 4 
Item 5 
   - Item 6 
   - Item 7

Ideally, as the screen size is reduced, I would like Item 4 to become a child of item 5.

Comment: You are asking for something to custom built.  Have you attempted anything?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have recently implemented the same. Here's just one example of [priority navigation](https://codepen.io/tibomahe/pen/xVaGaZ).

There is no default way to accomplish this in Joomla, or any other CMS I have come across. How you would implement this would be dependent on the template that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the sub menu items using aliases and you can show / hide menu options using custom CSS with media queries.

You may need to add link classes to the menu options to be able to specify each menu option in the custom CSS.